# Constant for that access sampler

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following GLSL code:

```
for( int i=0; i<3; ++i ) {
    finalColor += texture2D(myTextures[i],uv);
}
```

My opengl driver gives me the following output: "error: sampler arrays indexed with non-constant expressions is forbidden in GLSL 1.30 and later"

I could unroll the loop by hand, but I was wondering if there is a way to rewrite the `for` to make the GLSL compiler understand that my `i` can be resolved at compile time.

Observation: I am using intel driver on a linux machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the compiler could unroll the loop and this resolve `i` at compile time does *not* change the fact that `i` is not an integral constant expression. And therefore, it is not allowed to be used as an index in GLSL 1.20.

So no, there's nothing you can do outside of unrolling the loop manually.

Also, this restriction is lifted in GLSL 4.00+; there, you may use a [dynamically uniform expression (which your loop counter is)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Dynamically_Uniform_Expression).